# Decompiling DotNet2JScript malware?

Tags: windows, decompilation, malware, .net

I've got a .NET malware sample that was transpiled to JScript using [DotNet2JScript](https://github.com/tyranid/DotNetToJScript). The .NET malware assembly was serialized to binary form using BinaryFormatter and then embedded into the JScript source code. How can I transform the serialized malware assembly back to PE-file, so I can analyze it using dnSpy and similar tools? Or is there any tool that can parse metadata from serialized assemblies? Thanks!

Comment: I used [netfleece](https://pypi.org/project/netfleece/) to decode BinaryFormatter files.